# Use a default PHP script for all sub directories of a domain

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I am in the process of writing a website.  The design that I am using for the website uses the history API to change the URL in the address bar when page content changes via JavaScript and AJAX.  However, I want the different "pages" on the website to be available by accessing the URL that has been placed in the address bar as well.

My Idea for this involves getting the page URL in PHP and parsing it to determine what content needs to be loaded.  The only problem that I can see with this is that the script I am creating will only be accessible in the single directory that I am placing it.

My question is:

**How do I make my PHP script load whenever any subdirectory of the domain is loaded?**

(etc, loading the same php script when domain.com is loaded as when domain.com/4jklj234k or domain.com/about is loaded) (without having to copy the script to every location I want it to load on)

*THANKS!!*

EDIT: This functionality of loading the same script for every subdirectory is used by CMSs such as wordpress.

Comment: If you want to do it yourself, mod_rewrite for apache or pretty much any other web server has an equivalent. Even better though, get a simple php micro framework to route requests. Still uses mod_rewrite (or similar) but allows you to map urls to files easier.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn how would I make a php microframework?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn or get one?

Comment: micro framework was just a suggestion. You funnel all requests to the website through one script and then the framework just makes it easy to map that uri (the part of the url after the domain) to a function or include another script that gets called. So for example you map something like `/products/productName/` to call a function defined `function products($name){...}`. It doesn't do the url_rewrite part, but helps call pages once that mapping was done. You can also search for "php bootstrapping" which is what this was called for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

absolute minimum

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php
```

the technical term is **Front Controller** :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern